# Control centered mouse in 3D game

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code which controls the mouse (modified from [this source](https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-mouse-move-and-mouse-click-macro/)):

```
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub Control()
  Wait 3000
  Pos 6, 145
  Down
  Pos 6, 149
  Up
  Pos 7, 147
  Down
  Up
  Pos 8, 145
  Down
  Pos 8, 149
  Up
  Pos 10, 145
  Down
  Pos 10, 149
  Up
  Pos 11, 145
  Down
  Pos 12, 145
  Up
  Pos 11, 147
  Down
  Up
  Pos 11, 149
  Down
  Pos 12, 149
  Up
  Pos 14, 145
  Down
  Pos 14, 149
  Up
  Pos 15, 149
  Down
  Pos 16, 149
  Up
  Pos 18, 145
  Down
  Pos 18, 149
  Up
  Pos 19, 145
  Down
  Pos 20, 145
  Up
  Pos 20, 146
  Down
  Pos 20, 146
  Up
  Pos 19, 147
  Down
  Pos 20, 147
  Up
End Sub
Private Function Wait(Optional ByVal milliseconds As Long = 50)
  Sleep milliseconds
End Function
Private Function Pos(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
  SetCursorPos x, y
End Function
Private Function Down()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Function
Private Function Up()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Function
```

It works as expected and can draw on paint.

Now what I'm trying to accomplish is drawing in 3D in the game VRChat which centers the mouse to the middle of the screen.

In the game the mouse's down and up events work but trying to change the position of it doesn't move it at all.

The code works outside the game but doesn't work in the game to move the camera which is controlled by the mouse. What I'm looking for is to be able to move the mouse/camera in the game automatically with the code.

[image: VRChat 3D Drawing]

Comment: Relative to what?

Comment: relative to current cursor position i quess

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code, you can use to move cursor in a loop

```
'Declare mouse events
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
'Declare sleep
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub CityscapeSkyline()
'Open MS Paint and select Natural pencil Brush with 6px width
For k = 1 To 3
  SetCursorPos 16, 500
  Sleep 50
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
  For i = 16 To 600 Step 5
    For j = 500 To 300 Step -Int((180 - 10 + 1) * Rnd + 10)
      SetCursorPos i, j
      Sleep 10
    Next j
  Next i
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
Next k
End Sub
```

If you need to use current cursor position as well then you can integrate `GetCursorPos` as well

```
Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long
' Create custom variable that holds two integers
Type POINTAPI
   Xcoord As Long
   Ycoord As Long
End Type

Sub GetCursorPosDemo()
Dim llCoord As POINTAPI
' Get the cursor positions
GetCursorPos llCoord
' Display the cursor position coordinates
MsgBox "X Position: " & llCoord.Xcoord & vbNewLine & "Y Position: " & llCoord.Ycoord
End Sub
```

PS: Credits to https://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/vba-mouse-move-and-mouse-click-macro/

Comment: The problem is that the game doesn't detect or prevent the mouse/player camera from moving. It works on any other application.

Comment: @user7393973, I actually didn't get what your statement exactly mean.

Comment: This code moves the mouse on  the computer just fine but when try to move the camera (which is controled by the mouse) in the game it doesn't move.

Comment: I assume that would be happening based on keeping left mouse button clicked and moving the mouse?

Comment: To move the camera in the game I only need to move the mouse. Left clicking is to draw.

Comment: It may be some kind of low level mouse hook in the game which might be making this not work, can't say much

Comment: Yes, its probably something like that. I really just wanted to be able to do perfect drawings in seconds with perfect positioning but I guess its harder than I wanted :)

Comment: @user7393973, can you try one workaround, run your excel with admin rights and see if it helps. I just found one forum reply which said it worked after admin rights

Comment: Just started working, gonna have to wait until I get home. But if that works I'm going to thank you so god damn much. Still I have a feeling it won't but idk.

Comment: Here is thread that I was talking about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23920718/cursor-postition-and-mouse-event-being-blocked

Comment: The thing is that in the game the mouse is just the center of the screen that pulls outwards which is probably why it doesn't work. I don't know how that works but it's probably different the movement of the mouse vs moving the mouse in the screen.

Comment: I tried to learn how to use [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) but only got it working with the keyboard.

Comment: Also another thing to keep in mind, the mouse down and up events did worked in the game.

Comment: @user7393973, did you get a chance to check it out?

Answer (score 0):

Use GetCursorPos API to get the current cursor position and then make a relative offset. `PosRel(xOffSet As Long, yOffSet As Long)` <-- this sub does exactly this.

Below your code now modified to include supporting declarations, the PosRel sub and a sub for testing the cursor does the relative movements

```
Option Explicit
Public Declare Function SetCursorPos Lib "user32" (ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dx As Long, ByVal dy As Long, ByVal cButtons As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN As Long = &H8
Public Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP As Long = &H10
Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

''ADDED
    Declare Function GetCursorPos Lib "user32" (lpPoint As POINTAPI) As Long

    ' GetCursorPos requires a variable declared as a custom data type
    ' that will hold two integers, one for x value and one for y value
    Type POINTAPI
       X_Pos As Long
       Y_Pos As Long
    End Type


    Public Sub Test()
        Dim beforePOS As POINTAPI, afterPOS As POINTAPI

        GetCursorPos beforePOS
        PosRel 500, -500
        GetCursorPos afterPOS

        MsgBox "Before (" & beforePOS.X_Pos & "," & beforePOS.Y_Pos & ") " & vbNewLine & "After (" & afterPOS.X_Pos & "," & afterPOS.Y_Pos & ") "
    End Sub
    Public Sub PosRel(xOffSet As Long, yOffSet As Long)
        Dim currentPOs As POINTAPI
        GetCursorPos currentPOs
        SetCursorPos currentPOs.X_Pos + xOffSet, currentPOs.Y_Pos + yOffSet

    End Sub
''END ADDED

Sub Control()
  Wait 3000
  Pos 6, 145
  Down
  Pos 6, 149
  Up
  Pos 7, 147
  Down
  Up
  Pos 8, 145
  Down
  Pos 8, 149
  Up
  Pos 10, 145
  Down
  Pos 10, 149
  Up
  Pos 11, 145
  Down
  Pos 12, 145
  Up
  Pos 11, 147
  Down
  Up
  Pos 11, 149
  Down
  Pos 12, 149
  Up
  Pos 14, 145
  Down
  Pos 14, 149
  Up
  Pos 15, 149
  Down
  Pos 16, 149
  Up
  Pos 18, 145
  Down
  Pos 18, 149
  Up
  Pos 19, 145
  Down
  Pos 20, 145
  Up
  Pos 20, 146
  Down
  Pos 20, 146
  Up
  Pos 19, 147
  Down
  Pos 20, 147
  Up
End Sub
Private Function Wait(Optional ByVal milliseconds As Long = 50)
  Sleep milliseconds
End Function
Private Function Pos(ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long)
  SetCursorPos x, y
  DoEvents
End Function
Private Function Down()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Function
Private Function Up()
  mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0
End Function
```

Comment: The problem is that the game doesn't detect or prevent the mouse/player camera from moving. It works on any other application.

Comment: Then your issue is VRChat and not VBA, I suggest that you use their Unity SDK to solve your problem.  https://www.vrchat.net/developerfaq

Comment: I don't think anything in the SDK helps to control the mouse/camera/player's movements. The code works anywhere else but not in the game even though the mouse is used to move the camera.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what your using, just a different style, but I'm able to put the mouse exactly where I want it on the screen. I'm using dual monitors, so the coords may be a little different.

```
Private Declare Sub mouse_event Lib "user32" (ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
                                          ByVal dx As Long, _
                                          ByVal dy As Long, _
                                          ByVal cButtons As Long, _
                                          ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE = &H1          ' mouse move
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = &H2      ' left button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = &H4        ' left button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = &H8     ' right button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = &H10      ' right button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = &H20   ' middle button down
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = &H40     ' middle button up
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = &H800       ' wheel button rolled
Private Const MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE = &H8000   ' absolute move

Private Type POINTAPI
    x As Long
    y As Long
End Type


Sub myClick()
    Dim pt As POINTAPI
    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long

    '(0,0) = top left
    '(65535,65535) = bottom right
    x = 18800
    y = 11600

    LeftClick x, y
End Sub

Sub LeftClick(x As Long, y As Long)
'Move mouse
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, x, y, 0, 0

'Press left click
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0

'Release left click
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

'Trying a wait here..
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))

'Move to bottom of the screen
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE, 40000, 47000, 0, 0

'Trying a wait here..
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

'Try to scroll the page down
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL, 0, 0, -490, 0

'Trying a wait here..
'Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:00"))

'Press left click
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, 0

'Release left click
mouse_event MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE + MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 0, 0, 0, 0

End Sub
```

Comment: That's pretty much the same that I started with and what is in the other answers. It does move the mouse anywhere in the computer but the problem is that it doesn't in the game which is what I'm trying to find out how so I can make it draw something perfectly or whatever like a robot and pretty fast.